# Populate DefaultTableModel from test file

Tags: java

I have this text file:

```
A
B
3.00

A
B
3.00
```

and my view is:

[image: view]

I want to match each row with each column(first_row-first_column,second_row-second_column, etc..) Where have I made a mistake?
My code is as follows:

```
    BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader(reader);
        String line = "";
        int counter = 0;
        String title = "";
        String author = "";
        String price = "";
        try {
            while ((line  = infile.readLine()) != null) {
                ++counter;

                if (counter == 1) {
                    title = line;
                } else if (counter == 2) {
                    author = line;
                } else if (counter == 3) {
                    price = line;
                    SimpleBook sb = new SimpleBook(title, author, price);
                    bookList.add(sb);
                    counter = 0;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SimpleBookList.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do this as there is an blank line in your input file  .

```
BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader(reader);
    String line = "";
    int counter = 0;
    String title = "";
    String author = "";
    String price = "";
    try {
        while ((line  = infile.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line.isEmpty())
                  continue;

            ++counter;

            if (counter == 1) {
                title = line;
            } else if (counter == 2) {
                author = line;
            } else if (counter == 3) {
                price = line;
                SimpleBook sb = new SimpleBook(title, author, price);
                bookList.add(sb);
                counter = 0;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SimpleBookList.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your counter is incrementing at the begining of loop, so you never have 0 but 1 on if statement. Then empty line is parsed as 1 and goes to A column. You can solve it in multpile ways like skip empty lines or increment counter if line is not empty.